# How to get access to server token for riders API?

Tags: uber-api

I'm trying to play around with Uber Riders API. But it doesn't provide the server token by default. All the existing documentation says it'll be available by default but looks like docs are updated recently. How to get access to server token?

Comment: Did you get the server token. Even I am not able to connect to their Business Development team to get it.

Comment: @Anukoolsrivastav Did you get the server token?

Comment: @MinkleGarg i did not got any response from Uber. I guess they have new API to access the information.